# JS - standalone user-input date interpreter

Tags: javascript, node.js, date, parsing

I've spent literal hours searching the web for a JS library or a Node module that does just one thing: interpret user-input dates of all kinds (just english is fine) and converts them to a standard date.

For example, it should be able to recognize and convert the following into actual dates:

```
tomorrow 
in a year
last week
in 8 hours
in 4 months
8 8 90
65
```

[Sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/dates) does this, however I don't want all its other features, and it extends native objects. Moment.js deprecated its ability to do this as they consider it too opinionated - fine.

One would think someone made a library for this. Does anyone know of any?

Answer (score 2):

In cases like this where a library provides a functionality that I need but I do not need the entire library, I will just strip out the portion of the library that I need.

Sugar.js actually provided a customize option, so this is even easier to do.

http://sugarjs.com/customize

Additionally if you use bower or npm for your package management, there is already a package that just has the Date functions from Sugar.js:

https://github.com/fiznool/sugar-date